# AWS Redshift - Copy data from s3 with wildcard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to copy data from S3 bucket into Redshift using `copy` command. 
When I pass the exact file name in copy command it works perfectly fine but when I use wildcard (`*`) in my from clause it throws an error - **"The specified S3 prefix 'suiteX*' does not exist;"**

All my files follow this naming convention - `SuiteX_Date_Hour.csv`  for example - `SuiteX-20150101-1.csv`

Here is my copy command that works :

```
copy mytable from 's3://mybucket/suiteX_20150101_1.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXX'
delimiter ',' REGION AS 'us-east-1';
```

Here is the copy command that does not work:

```
copy mytable from 's3://mybucket/suiteX*'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXX' 
delimiter ',' REGION AS 'us-east-1';
```

Any idea how can make copy command to work with wildcard when I copy data from S3 ?

Answer (score 12):

The redshift COPY command doesn't have an explicit wildcard syntax. The object path you provide is treated like a prefix, and *any* matching objects will be COPY-ed. If the object path matches multiple folders, *all* objects in *all* those folders will be COPY-ed.

You should be able to get it to work for your example with:

```
copy mytable
from s3://mybucket/suiteX' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXX' 
delimiter ',' 
REGION AS 'us-east-1';
```

The relevent section from the [COPY from Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-source-s3.html#copy-parameters-data-source-s3-examples) docs says:

> FROM 's3://copy_from_s3_objectpath'
>
> Specifies the path to the Amazon S3 objects that contain the data—for example, 's3://mybucket/cust.txt'. The s3://copy_from_s3_objectpath parameter can reference a single file or a set of objects or folders that have the same key prefix. For example, the name custdata.txt is a key prefix that refers to a number of physical files: custdata.txt.1, custdata.txt.2, and so on. The key prefix can also reference a number of folders. For example, 's3://mybucket/custfolder' refers to the folders custfolder_1, custfolder_2, and so on. If a key prefix references multiple folders, all of the files in the folders will be loaded.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Redshift docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html#r_COPY-copy-from-amazon-s3-synopsis), I don't think COPY command supports wildcard for s3 file source path. Instead, you can specify a bucket directory as follows.

```
copy data
from 's3://mybucket/data/'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret-access-key>';
```

In this case, the files under `data/` directory will be copied to Redshift.

Comment: from 's3://mybucket/data/' does not work. instead have some prefix to the files those are copied in S3 bucket / folder inside bucket folder. e.g. all files inside s3://mybucket/data/ should have prefix as 'File_' in the filename. The update the from clause in the COPY command as 's3://mybucket/data/File_'. This works fine.